# What is the tensor product $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, tensor-products, cyclotomic-fields

Let $m \in \mathbb{N}^*$. Denote the $m$-th cyclotomic polynomial by $\Phi(x)$ and a complex primitive $m$-th root of unity by $\omega$.

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle \Phi(x) \rangle$ (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$).

So, I know that the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle \Phi(x) \rangle$) and therefore can be seen as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module of dimension $\varphi(m)$.

I also know that $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, however with bases of infinity cardinality.

But the tensor product is computed by tensoring vectors in each basis. Then, how could I define the set $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{R}$? Are the elements therein polynomials?

**More context**

I have found such tensor product in Lemma 3 of [this article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/127.pdf#page=10).

Comment: This tensor product is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ depending on the property of $\Phi(x)$ having complex roots or not. As long as $m\geq 3$, then it is equal to $\mathbb{C}$. Look up [extension of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules#Extension_of_scalars).

Comment: Not quite right, @Kolja: you’ll have $\phi(m)/2$ copies of the complex numbers. See my comment to Ben’s answer below.

Comment: True, I overlooked that. It's $\mathbb{R}[x]/(\Phi(x))$ which is just a product of $\frac{\phi(m)}{2}$ copies of $\mathbb{C}$ or equal to $\mathbb{R}$ if $m=1,2$. Nevertheless it's an example of extension of scalars, and still I reccoment to Vitor to read the wiki article on that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Kolja I will read more about it. Thank you both for the comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, $\mathcal O_K$ is not a $\mathbb Q$-vector space, so I presume it's a type which should say $\mathcal O_K \otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb R$. This tensor product is a change of base rings / extension of scalars, so:

$$\mathcal O_K\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb R = \mathbb R[x]/(\Phi(x))$$ Yes, the elements are equivalence classes of polynomials. However, you don't need to think about $\mathbb R$ being an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$ here, that's what you would do if you considered this as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space or abelian group. It's more appropriate to view it just as a finite dimensional real vector space.

Comment: But the significant thing about it is that $\cal O\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb R$ has the structure of a ring, in fact of a $\phi(m)$-dimensional $\Bbb R$-algebra. More than that, it’s $\bigoplus_f\Bbb R[X]/(f)$, where the index $f$ runs through all real-irreducible factors of $\Phi$. Since these factors all are quadratic (except in the trivial cases $m=1,2$), the upshot is that $\cal O\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb R$ is ring-direct sum of $\phi(m)/2$ copies of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @Lubin $\varphi(m)/2$ copies of $\mathbb C$ is basically the same thing as $\varphi(m)$ copies of $\mathbb R$, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks @Lubin I neglected these points

Comment: Not really, because these are rings. Multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$ is not the same as multiplication in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.